# jQuery can not run many times click button

Tags: jquery

I have 1 html page containing 4 divs and 1 button. I use jQuery and expect when clicking on the button, the system checks if the content of div2 is empty and div3, div4 is empty then adds content for div2. If the content of div2 is non-empty and div3, div4 is empty, then add the content for div3, ...
I want to click first, then check the content of div2 and add content for div2, the second time, check the content of div3 and add content for div3, ...

The code I ran below only added div2 and it didn't add content to div3 or div4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'
src='D:/test/jquery-form/jquery-3.4.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#div2").empty();
$("#div3").empty();
$("#div4").empty();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){

if(($("#div1").text().length>0)&&($("#div2").text().length===0))
{
$("#div2").append("<input type=text name=t2 value='service2'>");


} else if(($("#div2").text().length>0)&&($("#div3").text().length===0))
{
$("#div3").append("<input type=text name=t3 value='service3'>");

}
else if(($("#div2").text().length>0)&&(($("#div3").text().length>0))&&($("#div4").text().length===0))
{
$("#div4").append("<input type=text name=t4 value='service4'>");

}

});
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="intl">
<div id="div1">
service 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
service 2
</div>
<div id="div3">
service 3
</div>
<div id="div4">
service 4
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean "Each subsequent click should put content into the next <div> in the series"? If so this would be way easier to do by having a counter variable and just dumping content into `$("#div" + n)` where `n` is your counter starting at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#div2").empty();
$("#div3").empty();
$("#div4").empty();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){

if(($("#div1").html().length>0)&&($("#div2").html().length===0))
{
$("#div2").append("<input type=text name=t2 value='service2'>");


} else if(($("#div2").html().length>0)&&($("#div3").html().length===0))
{
$("#div3").append("<input type=text name=t3 value='service3'>");

}
else if(($("#div2").html().length>0)&&(($("#div3").html().length>0))&&($("#div4").html().length===0))
{
$("#div4").append("<input type=text name=t4 value='service4'>");

}

});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<intput type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="click me" />Click Me
<br />
<div id="intl">

<div id="div1">
service 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
service 2
</div>
<div id="div3">
service 3
</div>
<div id="div4">
service 4
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```